# Add detail to Codeigniter Logs

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

All the errors I'm interested in debugging in Codeigniter's log files are reporting that they come from `/system/core/Loader.php` when they don't. For example, here's a line:

```
ERROR | 2014-09-22 22:35:43 | "Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: my_variable \/system\/core\/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code 84"
```

I know which file this is coming from, and it's a view. I'm aware of [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and I'm thinking about making a string of it and concatenating it onto the end of the `$msg` variable in an overridden `Log.php`, but I first wanted to check two things with all you friends:

1. Is `debug_backtrace` the best way to do this? It returns a huge amount of data.
2. Is anyone aware of someone that's already done this? Seems like an obvious need for anyone using Codeigniter (...still ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code you *could adapt* to your needs (I recommend creating a My_Log and not editing the system file just in case CI does ever get an update).  The reason I have this is complicated and not useful as-is any longer, but it might give you a start:

```
protected function log_query ($query, $type)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace ();
    $backtrace = array_slice ( $backtrace, 2, -2 ); // first and last two elements are things that never change

    $traced    = array ();

    foreach ( $backtrace as $bt )
    {

        $func   = isset ( $bt['function'] ) ? $bt['function'].'()' : '';
        $line   = isset ( $bt['line'] )     ? $bt['line']          : '';
        $file   = isset ( $bt['file'] )     ? str_replace ( APP, '', $bt['file'] ) : '';
        $object = isset ( $bt['object'] )   ? get_class ( $bt['object'] ) : '';
        $args   = array (); build_args ( $bt['args'], $args );
        $args   = implode ( '; ', $args );

        if ( $object )
        {
            $obj_func = $object . '->' . $func;
        } else {
            $obj_func = $func;
        }

        $traced[] = "$file $obj_func $line $args";
        unset($args);
    }

    $traced = implode ( "\n\t", $traced );

    $date = MYSQL_DATE_TIME;
    $uri  = isset ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '' ;
    $query= preg_replace ( "/[\n\t]/", ' ', $query );

    log_message ('error', "{$query}\n\n\t{$date} ({$type})\n\t{$uri}\n\t{$traced}\n--------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my direction is reasonable!